# limit words in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an input box named "title".

I want the user to only enter 35 words not more than that.

```
<input name="title" id="title" class="event-name gui-input" placeholder="Title" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#title").validate({
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please enter Title"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: @Tushar is maxlength used for characters?not words?

Comment: i need a script that will tell the user as he type that 20 words remaining and so on

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a free programming service, you request, we code.If you aren't sure where to start, why not use `.split()` and count the arrays that return. "Split from each space"

Comment: i didnt asked for free code @NewToJS i have given my jquery script above i want to know how could i stop user from writing more words... ok dude?

Comment: @AniketSingh I understand what you wish to achieve and it's nice of you to display your validation script but that doesn't show any attempt/sign of trying to limit or count word in a string.

Comment: @AniketSingh you are not confused with `word` and `character` right?

Answer (score 6):

Use the JavaScript `split` method:

```
var content = $("input#title").val() //content is now the value of the text box
var words = content.trim().split(/\s+/); //words is an array of words, split by space
var num_words = words.length; //num_words is the number of words in the array

if(num_words>35){
    //too many words
    return false;
}
```

Hopefully this helps and you can adapt this code to your validation.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb3t9L8d/)**

---

One-line solution to return the number of words in the input:

```
var num_words = $("input#title").val().trim().split(/\s+/).length;
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b77a9L5m/)**

Comment: Put what you want in the `if` statement to get a response. Edit it to your liking. For example, `if(num_words>35){ alert("too long"); } else { alert("length is fine"); }`

Comment: I'd use `\s+` to split words

Comment: Also `trim()` to remove the spaces at the end of the string otherwise it will return an empty array but still count it as a word.

Comment: @NewToJS Not required when used `\s+` to split words

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, you're correct - added regex and JSFiddle example.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Just my observation if i type 1 word then put space the count is 2. Please check

Comment: Try this. Minor edit as I pointed out the use of `trim()` will fix the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/6qdaue92/1/

Comment: Thanks @NewToJS - added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the solution provided by Ben.
Providing the user to know how many words are left.

Script...

```
 $("#title").keyup(function(){

   var content = $("#title").val(); //content is now the value of the text box
   var words = content.split(/\s+/); //words is an array of words, split by space
   var num_words = words.length; //num_words is the number of words in the array
   var max_limit=35;
    if(num_words>max_limit){
        alert("Exceeding the max limit");
        var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(" ");
            $("#title").val(content.substring(0, lastIndex));

       $('#remainingChars').text('Limit Exceeding');
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
    $('#remainingChars').text(max_limit+1-num_words +" words remaining");
    }
    });
```

Form fields..

```
  <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="100" /> 
    <div id="remainingChars">Max limit is 35 words.</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2drkoe5/)

Comment: You mean you have made a few changes to an existing answer trying to take the mark for it... changes to an answer should be suggested in the comments, not reposted.

Comment: That is why I mentioned. to provide a better solution. NOT FOR THE MARK

Comment: This also has the same issue of counting a word if the user puts a space at the end. `example ` <- will count as two words. `trim()` will fix this issue http://jsfiddle.net/ortbyo9f/

Comment: That is a good point. Thanks :) Now You can take the mark bro ;) Cheers!!

Comment: I haven't submitted an answer as I would offer the same but with very few changes, hence making a suggestion to make the answers better. You don't get marked in comments *bro* :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use max length in input field.

```
<input name="title" id="title" class="event-name gui-input" 
placeholder="Title" type="text"  maxlength="35">
```

Comment: `maxlength` is for **characters** - the OP is looking for a count of **words**.

Answer (score 0):

You can write following logic on `keyup` event

35 words = 34 spaces

1. Create a counter to count number of spaces
2. Just check for (n-1) value of counter where n is Number of words.
3. Display error message in case user is going beyond that.